# How to find my label in absolute layout in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have developed one page in xamarin (VS2015) in absolute layout with a bunch of labels in it and I have differentiate them by giving unique automation ID (one of the properties of each label) to each label.

```
<Label x:Name="abc" AutomationId="2000" Text="300"  FontSize="Micro" TextColor="Yellow" BackgroundColor="Black" ></Label>
```

Now i want to check label dynamically with no any hard code.

I can able to detect label in layout child by mention unique id but it's giving me in `xamarin.forms.view`

```
int autoID = Convert.ToInt16(absolutelayout.Children[i].AutomationId);
```

now i want to convert in label. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've fully understood your question, it's a bit hard to read.

I assume that you are looping through the children of the absolute layout. and want to get the automationId of all Labels within the layout.

```
foreach (var child in absolutelayout.Children){ 
var childAsLabel = child as Label; 
if (childAsLabel != null){ 
int autoID = Convert.ToInt16(childAsLabel.AutomationId); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to abuse `AutomationId` for this. In `WPF` (or `Silverlight`, or whatever else), you'd use the `Tag` property, but `Xamarin.Forms` doesn't provide a

```cs
object Tag { get; set; }
```

property. The reason for the omission is quite simple. You can provide the capability yourself, using an attached BindableProperty.

```cs
public class TagHelper
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Tag", typeof(object), typeof(TagHelper), default(object));

    public static object GetTag(BindableObject bindable)
    {
        return (object)bindable.GetValue(TagProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindable, object value)
    {
        bindable.SetValue(TagProperty, value);
    }
}
```

and you tag your `Label` like this:

```xml
<Label ... local:TagHelp.Tag="myTag" .../>
```

Now if you want to find the label with "myTag" in your `AbsoluteLayout` it isn't hard:

```cs
var label = layout.Children.FirstOrDefault(v => TagHelper.GetTag(v) == "myTag") as Label;
```

If you really insist on using `AutomationId` (you shouldn't), this should work

```cs
//DON'T
var label = layout.Children.FirstOrDefault(v => v.AutomationId == "2000") as Label;
```